# isomorphism demonstration

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I just need to check that my reasoning is sound and there is no logical problem.
Assume A, B and C are sets. A and B are separately isomorphic to C. I want to prove that

$A\times B \cong C \times C $

There must be two invertible functions $\phi_{A}:A\rightarrow C, \phi_{B}:B\rightarrow C$. Then, I would explicitly define

$\psi:A\times B \rightarrow C\times C$
as $\psi(a,b) = (\phi_A(a), \phi_B(b))$

and this should be an isomorphism since the inverse can be defined as

$\psi^{-1}(c_1,c_2) = (\phi^{-1}_A(c_1), \phi^{-1}_B(c_2))$

Is this in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Looks perfect to me, although your notation for the inverse is a little awkward; I would read the tuple $(a, b)$ as being in $A \times B$; consequently, I would prefer to read the inverse as $\psi^{-1} : C \times C \to A \times B$ given by $\psi^{-1}(c_1, c_2) = (\phi_A^{-1}(c_1), \phi_B^{-1}(c_2))$.

Comment: of course, right you are :-) thanks

Comment: fixed it! thanks again